# Dividing polygon into tiny polygons of particular size

Tags: pyqgis, arcgis-10.0, polygon, qgis-3, mathematics

I would like to divide/cut an irregular polygon into tiny polygons of a particular size(1.6m x 1m) in such a way that most of the irregular polygon area has to be utilized (an OPTIMIZATION MODEL)

The length and width of the polygon can be interchanged (either 1.6m X 1m (or) 1m X 1.6m)

So, in the end, I need to have as many polygons of size (1.6m X 1m) as possible.

[image]

I used the "Create Grid" feature but it just cuts the whole polygon in a particular fashion.

[image]

But what I also want is that here, a blue polygon can also be cut in a vertical manner(1m x 1.6m) too.

[image]

So, I would like to know where there is a plugin for this in QGIS/ArcGIS or any python script for this kind of polygon optimization?

Comment: Welcom to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. By specifying multiple software stacks you are asking multiple questions. Please choose one software environment, make an attempt to solve the issue in that environment, and [Edit] the Question to focus on the software and procedure used.